# How to get access to the value of object from the Json in response body when GET request is sent?

Tags: sql, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass JSON from stored procedure. So I am passing it as string and entity class contain string data type which capture this string from stored procedure.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateJson]
    @AppointmentID int
AS
    DECLARE @JsonOutput AS nvarchar(max)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @JsonOutput = (SELECT TOP 1 AppointmentID, ReturnCode
                       FROM appointments
                       WHERE appointmentID = @AppointmentID
                       FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) 

    SELECT @JsonOutput AS Details
END
```

Entity class:

```
public partial class sp_test
{
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

API controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<sp_test>>> Getsp_test(int AppointmentID)
{
    string StoredJson = "exec CreateJson " +
            "@AppointmentID = " + AppointmentID;
    var result = await _context.sp_test.FromSqlRaw(StoredJson).ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Response body:

```
[
  {
    "details": "{\"AppointmentID\":1,\"ReturnCode\":1}"
  }
]
```

I want to get that JSON which is showing corresponding to details. And I want to use that JSON as parameter to call another API. I am unable to access that JSON.

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls Getsp_test pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this code to GET data

```
var appointemntId= ...from your code
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var baseAddress = "http://...";
   
     var api = "/< controllerName >/Getsp_test?AppointmentId="+appointmentId.ToString();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(api);
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<sp_test>>(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to code in controller only, because this code will written in program.cs ?

Comment: And how will you call stored procedure from it?